# converting to path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I have a little complicated shape which is created in blend however, I need to use it in the code as part of setter so I'm trying to use "Convert to Path" in Blend but this menu/command is disabled. The only available option is "make compound path" but it messes up the shape, even using the latter option generates a complicated  segment which i have no idea how to use in setter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anything in a setter, there should be no need to boil it down, just use element syntax, e.g.

```
<Setter Property="LoremIpsum">
    <Setter.Value>
         <Geometry>
              <!-- ... -->
         </Geometry>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You need to be careful with objects that con only have one parent, e.g. framework elements, as the setter only creates one instance which is used for all controls using the style.